# Get a node to show up underneath a View's menu item

Tags: drupal, view

So I've got a content type of "News" and then a View which shows a list of News nodes as a menu item.

Is there any way to highlight the News View in the menu tree when you're viewing a News node?

I'm sort of aware of why this doesn't work, and why doing this might be hacky, but there's got to be a way to have a "default" menu item or something that a node can show up under.

Comment: So that I understand your question correctly (and trying to put it in typical Drupal terminology), are you trying to apply a special style class to a particular block (your News view block) when viewing a particular type of node (Views)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found a module that does basically what the template.php answer above does, by allowing you to assign a default menu item by content type.

It's called [Menu Trails](https://www.drupal.org/project/menutrails). Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... adds some common-sense usability to Drupal's menu system
>
> - Menu Trails implements primary/secondary links which keep the current menu trail "active" or highlighted. A handy snippet ready to go into your template.php is included.
> - The module provides a means of broadly categorizing nodes (by type or taxonomy) as falling "under" a known menu item. These nodes are not added to the menu tree (keeping the menu admin system sane) but they will trigger the functionality above -- preserving navigation state for the user -- when viewed.
> - New for 6.0: Menu Trails can also set breadcrumbs for nodes, keeping them in sync with the trail.
> - New for 6.0: Menu Trails is now Organic Groups aware, so nodes can be designated to fall "under" the first group node they belong to.
> - New for 6.0: A token is exposed to pathauto (and other token-aware modules) allowing for the menu trail to be used in automatic path alias creation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the answer to my above comment is "yes," this is something you can accomplish through the template.php file in your theme folder

The final solution will depend on your settings, but generally most of the action will happen inside `phptemplate_preprocess_page`

```
// Simplified, and untested in this form
    function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {                        
      if (isset($vars['node'])) { // if we're looking at a node
        $body_classes[] = (($vars['node']->type == 'News') || (arg(0) == 'News')) ? 'news_page' : '';             // Page is news page
      }
      else if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy') {
        // ... Special handling for news taxonomy pages, if you want
      } else {
        $body_classes[] = "page-type-" . arg(0);
      }
      $body_classes = array_filter($body_classes); // Out! Out! Damn empty elements!
      $vars['body_classes'] = implode(' ', $body_classes);  
    }
```

This will give the you the `body.news_page` style class to work with, and you can combine that with the style of your news menu block to make it appear how you like.

Answer (score 0):

if Menutrails doesn't work (for me it didn't) you can do it yourself by something like:

`$somenode = menu_get_item('node/5');`

`menu_set_item($somenode);`

Answer (score 0):

I have found you have more control if you do something like this in hook_nodeapi().

```
// this code worked for me
$somenode = menu_get_item();
$somenode['href'] = 'node/5';
menu_set_item(NULL, $somenode);
```

You may need to set the weight of your custom module to be heavier than core modules: at least 1